# Retrieve elements from facts in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am currently learning Prolog for a class right now. I am using GNU Prolog to define a rule for example `class_info(X,Y)` and a similar rule, where `X` is the name of the professor and `Y` will be the output of the info. For example:

```
?- class_info(steve, Y). 
Y = math ;
false.
```

But I only know how to return algebraic expressions in rules, but not the one above.

Suppose I have the following facts.

```
/*facts */
job(steve, professor).
job(john, professor).

teaches(steve, math).
teaches(john, chemistry).

class(math, calculus).
class(chemistry, organic).
class(math, algebra).
class(chemistry, basic).


%rule
class_info(X, Y) :-
    %absolutely have no idea what do here, 'is' does not work, since it's only for algebraic expressions
 .

exact_class(X, Y) :-
 %exact_class(steve, Y). returns Y = calculus? and Y = algebra upon pressing ';'
 .
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am not looking for code, but something to point me in the right direction. The Prolog GNU manual is kind of hard to follow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class_info(X, Y) :-
    teaches(X, Y).

?- class_info(steve,Y).
Y = math ;
false.
```

Ok, sorry for putting one solution right on top but Prolog is hard to grasp without examples. So I just put the first solution, the second you have to figure out with a bit of explanation.

So you are asking which lecturer `X` holds which class `Y`. You already have this info within `teaches/2`, so you just forward the values from this predicate. So it says something like *if a teacher `X` teaches the lecture `Y`, the classinfo from `X` is `Y`*. You can add addional information, for example the teacher has to be a professor. You do this "and" (conjunction) by putting a `,` between the predicates:

```
class_info(X, Y) :-
    teaches(X, Y),
    job(X, professor).

?- class_info(steve,Y).
Y = math ;
false.
```

Please note that variables start with a capital letter. Questions are asked by starting with `?-`, the answers are separeted by a semicolon `;` until there are no solutions left (`false.`).

You can even be more specific about this by using a predicate which also forwards the lecturers job:

```
class_info_job(X, Y, Z) :-
    teaches(X, Y),
    job(X, Z).

?- class_info_job (steve, Y, Z).
Y = math,
Z = professor ; 
false.

?- class_info_job (steve, Y, professor).
Y = math; 
false.

?- class_info_job(X, math, Z).
X = steve,
Z = professor ;
false. 

?- class_info_job(X, Y, Z).
X = steve,
Y = math,
Z = professor ;
X = john,
Y = chemistry,
Z = professor ;
false.
```

Ok, so these were some examples how to play around. I hope this enough to help you with the second rule.

Comment: The goal is to do something like class_info(X, Y) :- job(X, Y), teaches(X, Y). but when running this, it returns no. Using '_' doesn't help.

Comment: I've got it figured out, thanks to your advice. I slightly changed it, and put ; instead of, such that it will output everything out (changed the code in above comment).